# imap_search criterion SUBJECT doesn't work

Tags: php, imap

When I try to get emails from server (it's mail.ru) with imap_search, criterion SUBJECT does not work.
I still have no success. Criteria like OLD, BEFORE, UNSEEN, UNANSWERED work fine.
Email server is mail.ru
PHP 8.2
I double-checked the subject text, it is correct. I tried as well to specify subject in English, still no success. I have same issue with FROM criterion.

Perhaps it's because the subject is in Cyrillic, but even if I do this:

```
imap_search(
   imap: $inbox,
   criteria: 'SUBJECT "Тест"',
   charset: 'UTF-8'
);
```

This query returns false, even though there is an email with "Тест" subject in the inbox.

Comment: `Perhaps it's because the subject is in Cyrillic`....well have you tested with a sample email where the subject is entirely in English, and tried to search for the English word? That would tell you more accurately if the problem relates to text encoding, or to something else.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, I tried a sample email with subject in English (subject was 'Test'), and it didn't work, either.

Comment: Well then, the problem is unlikely to be the Cyrillic text specifically, then. Silly question but...are you sure you're querying the correct inbox? Are you sure it's connected properly and you have permissions?

Comment: @ADyson I'm absolutely positive about that. I can easily access all emails and fetch their bodies. But for some reason, imap_search returns false when I use criteria UNSEEN or FROM

Comment: I’ve seen from others that mail.ru has terrible or non-existent text search.  This is a probably just a server limitation.

Comment: @Max Yes, you're right. It was mail.ru issue

Comment: I'll put up an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotally, `mail.ru` is an incomplete implementation of IMAP and appears not to support text-based searches (though flag based searches work)

That query should work fine on other servers that conform to IMAP. Otherwise you'd need to fetch all the subjects and search them yourself, client-side. With caching, this could be reasonably performant.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the query is wrong for IMAP4rev1 and cannot be expected to work with a conformant server, because it contains non-ASCII in a quoted string. Тест has to be sent as {8} followed by CR, LF and Тест. The number 8 because the four characters are 8 bytes of UTF8. IMAP4rev2 and some -1 implementations allow UTF-8 in quoted strings, but if "Тест" doesn't work, it *may* be because you've run into a strict parser.

Comment: @arnt True; I was making an assumption that the library was smart enough to use literals, which is not necessarily true.  The problem persists with ascii strings as well according to comments,

Comment: Right, mail.ru is broken, no question about that. I'm just commenting that the query can't be expected to work fine on conformant servers.